# What do we mean by 'converges faster'?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

In my analysis course the lecture has a few times compared the conergence of one limit to another, describing one as converging faster than the other does. What exactly does this mean formally?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence

Comment: Perhaps your question should be tagged rate-of-convergence too

Comment: Usually, one means $v_n$ converges faster to $L$ than $u_n$ if $\dfrac{v_n-L}{u_n-L}\to0$.

Comment: **(A)** Yes , that limit tending to $0$ is what I gave in my Answer Post , though I left out the limiting value , in order to highlight the term $1/x$ , @Jean-ClaudeArbaut , where that term will tend to $0$. It is more informative to see which term is tending to $0$ , to qualitatively & quantitatively indicate the fastness , Eg $1/x^3$ versus $1/x^6$ versus $3/x^6$. **(B)** More-over , when two functions have the Same Order of Convergence , that limit might be a Constant , where the functions might Differ by the Rate of Convergence.

Answer (score -2):

Ideally , you should give Specific Examples where the lecture Contents of your Analysis Course has said so.

Without that , I am making my own Examples , you can suitably alter it to your Examples.

Let $f(x)=1+1/x$ , $g(x)=1+2/x^2$ , $h(x)=1+1/x^2$ , where we want the limit $L$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$ : Naturally , the limit $L$ is $1$.

I Claim that $h(x)$ converges faster to that limit than $g(x)$ which converges faster to that limit than $f(x)$.

What I mean by that Claim :
$\exists X : \forall x>X , |h(x)-L| < |g(x)-L|$
$\exists X : \forall x>X , |g(x)-L| < |f(x)-L|$
$\exists X : \forall x>X , |h(x)-L| < |f(x)-L|$

Putting it alternatively :
$\exists X : \forall x>X , |h(x)-L| / |g(x)-L| < 1/2$
$\exists X : \forall x>X , |g(x)-L| / |f(x)-L| < 2/x$
$\exists X : \forall x>X , |h(x)-L| / |f(x)-L| < 1/x$

Intuitively , at every large value of $x$ , $h(x)$ is closer to the limit than $g(x)$ which is closer to the limit than $f(x)$.

Informally , $h(x)$ is twice fast compared to $g(x)$ which is infinitely fast compared to $f(x)$.

We can quantify the fastness , though that will take this Post too far.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really make sense to me.  The usual way in which we talk about rates of convergence is in terms of Landau's notation, and *classes* of functions which have similar convergence properties.  With respect to your examples, both $1 + 2/x^2$ and $1 + 1/x^2$ are in the class $O(1/x^2)$, so they converge equally quickly.

Comment: While I could have given 2 functions $f(x)$ & $g(x)$ , Deliberately , I gave the 3rd function to Specifically highlight that Point you raise , @XanderHenderson , about the Classes having functions which Differ by Constant. Here ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence ) it says there are 2 numbers to look at : the order of convergence & the rate of convergence , though these are not Standardized. [[ cont ]]

Comment: [[ cont ]] Adapting & Applying that terminology to my way of Explaining & my Examples , $f(x)$ belongs to order $1/x$ , both $g(x)$ & $h(x) belong to order $1/x^2$ where the rates Differ. The rate is immaterial when comparing 2 Classes. **The rate is necessary when comparing 2 functions of the Same Class.** This quantification is beyond the Question & Answer which was why I concluded with "We can quantify the fastness , though that will take this Post too far."